# What does it mean a function to belong to a space in the sense of distributions?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

In my book Sobolev's spaces are defined as follows

$$W^{m,p}(\Omega) = \{v \in L^p(\Omega): \,\, D^{\alpha}v \in L^p(\Omega) \,\, \forall \, |\alpha|\leq m \,\mbox{ in the sense of 
distributions} \}$$

I don't understand what he means by distributional sense. To be more specific in an example, what does mean $u \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}) $ in the distributional sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "in the sense of distributions" here refers to the differential operator $D^\alpha$. For example, $u \in W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$ if $u, Du \in L^1 (\mathbb{R})$, where $Du$ is the weak derivative, or derivative in the sense of distributions. This derivative is computed by "integrating" against an arbitrary smooth function with compact support $\phi$.

\begin{aligned}
\langle Du, \phi \rangle &= \int u^{'}  \phi \; dx \\ 
&= -\int u  \phi ^{'} \; dx
\end{aligned}
It's a way of extending the notion of differentiability to functions that are not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Perfect, now it's clear.

Comment: I think you left out the $\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ part of the explanation. Don't you need to say something like $Du\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $\exists f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $-\int u\phi'\,dx=\int f\phi\,dx$ for all smooth $\phi$ with compact support?